# How to let program to run instead of an exception in c#?

Tags: c#-4.0, exception

I am writing a program to read all files from an array.
Suppose in between if any file is corrupt or any reason it will stop the execution in between and throw an exception
I want to let the code running till end and at last it logged the error files instead of throwing exception?

Comment: You need to learn about [Exception Handling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229005.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

```
try{
   doSomethingThatMayRaiseAndException();
}
catch (Exception e){
    NotifyTheUserThatSomethingBadJustHappened();
}
```

Exception here is the base class for exceptions, you may need to use a more specific one if you want to provide the user with details. But right now, what you need to learn is how to deal with exceptions. You can use [the link provided by Oded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229005.aspx), it is a good start. Then note what is the raised exception you need to handle, and handle it.